# Why when I use tag f:event Constructor of ManagedBean has multiple calls?

Tags: jsf, constructor

I'm writing the project with ManagedBeans and I have the problem - multiple calls of constructor and multiple instances of beans. Source of test bean:

```
@Named(value = "newJSFManagedBean1")
@SessionScoped
public class NewJSFManagedBean1 implements Serializable {
    static private int createdcount = 0;

    public NewJSFManagedBean1() {
        createdcount++;
        System.out.println("Constructor.createdcount = " + createdcount);
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return this.getClass().getName() + ".createdcount=" + createdcount;
    }

    public void preRenderBean(ComponentSystemEvent cse) {
    }

}
```

In this case Constructor called one time:

```
<h:body>
    <h:outputText value="#{newJSFManagedBean1.message}"/>
</h:body>
```

Result is : createdcount=1 - and that's Ok

But if I add tag f:event Constructor of ManagedBean is getting called multiple times:

```
<h:body>
    <f:event listener="#{newJSFManagedBean1.preRenderBean}" type="preRenderComponent"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{newJSFManagedBean1.message}"/>
</h:body>
```

result is : createdcount=**3** - Why?

Thanks.